# Do addition of values while adding into array in PHP

Tags: php

I have values from database trying to add the next value with the initial value then insert into an array, can somebody help me here, please?

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {   
        $balance[]  =   (round($row["Balance"], 2))++;;
    }
```

Scenario:

I have `1,2,3,4,5` values
I want to get these values into an array as below:

```
{1,3,6,10,15}
```

That is:

```
{1, (1+2), (1+2+3), (1+2+3+4), (1+2+3+4+5)}
```

Any one with an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off just having a running total and adding this in...

```
$total = 0;
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
    $total = round($row["Balance"], 2) + $total;
    $balance[]  = $total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that:

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];

$b = [];

foreach($a as $c) {
    if(count($b) === 0) {
        $b[] = $c;
    } else {
        $b[] = end($b) + $c;
    }
}
```

`$b` is result.